# Limiting results of a triple join

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have a database with three tables, related with foreign keys:

Trips:

```
| ID| Number| Date|
------------------
```

Days:

```
| ID| TripID| Date| Start| End|
------------------------------
```

Legs:

```
| ID| DayID| Origin| Destination|
--------------------------------
```

I get data out of this database using the following join:

```
SELECT * FOM Trips t JOIN Days d
    ON t.Id = d.TripId
JOIN Legs l 
    ON d.Id = l.DayId
WHERE t.Id = tripId
```

Which returns a result containing one row for each leg associated with the queried trip that looks like:

```
| Trips.ID| Trips.Number| Trips.Date| Days.ID| Days.TripID| Days.Date| Days.Start| Days.End| Legs.ID| Legs.DayID| Legs.Origin| Legs.Destination|
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

This works fine for a specific trip ID, but say I run a query that returns multiple trips, for example

```
    SELECT * FROM Trips t JOIN Days d
       ON t.ID = d.TripID
    JOIN Legs l
       ON d.Id = l.DayId
    WHERE d.Date > date
```

How can I limit the result of the above query to a single trip, but still get all the rows associated with that trip?

Comment: Your question is a little confusing.  You say you select on a particular Tripid, but then mention that it could somehow return both TripA and TripB.  ...so TripA and TripB have the same TripID?  ...and if so, which table/column distinguishes them?  ...and when you say "first" trip, is that the earliest date in "trips", the earliest date in "days", or the earliest days.start (also not sure what data type days.start would be if that's relevant)

Comment: I have edited my question, hopefully it's more clear now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not 100% sure about the sqlite syntax (I'm more familiar with oracle), but I think this is what you want:

```
SELECT * FROM Trips t JOIN Days d
ON t.ID = d.TripID
JOIN Legs l
ON d.Id = l.DayId
WHERE d.ID IN (  
    SELECT ID FROM Days d WHERE d.date > date ORDER BY d.date LIMIT 1
)
```

Comment: Ah, that's a sub-query correct?  So the sub query selects all days that have a date > than specified and limits that to the first one.  Then the main query selects all trips where the day matches the one found in the sub-query.  Do I understand that correctly?  It seems that this will only return the rows for one day though rather than the whole trip that contains that day.

Comment: Yes, this is a subquery.  The subquery selects all `id`s from date that have a date > than a specified one, and limits to the first (earliest) one.  The main query selects all trips where the `id` (not the day) matches the one found in the subquery.  It should return all rows for this id.  It is equivalent to your original sql where you just gave it a specific id - that's all the subquery is doing.

Comment: Why not just join with the subquery instead of joining with the entire `Days` query?

Comment: He said he wants to _limit results to a single trip_. If there are multiple trips on the same day, this will return all of them. I think you need a subquery for `Trips` with `LIMIT 1`.

Comment: @Barmar:  You're correct.  I selected ID instead of TripId in my subclause (didn't look at his original query close enough).  Corrected.  A subquery on Trips might be even better (probably a smaller table).